# Swift 2.1 Delegation with NSObject

Tags: swift2, ios9, delegation

I'm working through an example below and received an error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> CentralViewController   
to expected argument type 'TransferServiceDelegate?'
```

I'm trying to complete a delegation, it is erring out when I'm trying to initialize 'scanner'.  Any help would be appreciated..thanks!:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


protocol TransferServiceScannerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didStartScan()
    func didStopScan()
    func didTransferData(data: NSData?)
}

class TransferServiceScanner: NSObject{
    weak var delegate: TransferServiceScannerDelegate?

    init(delegate: TransferServiceScannerDelegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }

}

class CentralViewController: UIViewController,
TransferServiceScannerDelegate {

   *let scanner: TransferServiceScanner = TransferServiceScanner(self)*

   func didStartScan(){}
   func didStopScan(){}
   func didTransferData(data: NSData?){}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way:

```
lazy var scanner: TransferServiceScanner = {
        let scanner = TransferServiceScanner(delegate: self)
        return scanner
    }()
```

I don't think use delegate in init is a good way and necessary, you also can do like this:

```
class TransferServiceScanner: NSObject{
    weak var delegate: TransferServiceScannerDelegate?

    init(delegate: TransferServiceScannerDelegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class CentralViewController: UIViewController,
TransferServiceScannerDelegate {

    var scanner: TransferServiceScanner = TransferServiceScanner()

    func didStartScan(){}
    func didStopScan(){}
    func didTransferData(data: NSData?){}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scanner.delegate = self
    }
}
```